# class not found when unit testing a custom module

Tags: phpunit, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I'm trying to write tests for a custom module I've written on Drupal 8 and keep getting an error and at this point I'm out of ideas. Here is the error:

`Error: Class 'Drupal\mypackage\Services\Config\MyClassServiceConfig' not found`

The PhpUnit class is under

`modules\custom\mypackage\tests\src\Unit\mypackageUserAuthTest`

Here is the code

```
class mypackageUserAuthTest extends UnitTestCase
{
    protected $user;
    protected $loginService;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->loginService = new LoginService();

        $this->user = [
            'username'  => 'xxx',
            'password'  => 'xxx',
            'deviceId'  => 'xxx',
            'some-token' => 'xxx'
        ];
    }

    /** @test */
    public function that_we_can_authenticate_a_user()
    {
        $IsUserLoggedIn = $this->loginService->login($this->user['username'], $this->user['password']);

        $this->assertTrue($IsUserLoggedIn);
    }
```

Now the method `login` in `loginService` code

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mypackage\Rest;

use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;

use Drupal\mypackage\Services\RestServiceFactory;
use Drupal\mypackage\Services\Config\MyClassServiceConfig;

class LoginService
{
    public function login($username, $password)
    {
        $configs = new MyClassServiceConfig(null, "mobile", "v1");
        $client  = RestServiceFactory::create($configs);

        try {
            $response = $client->post('login', [
                'json' => [
                        'username' => $username,
                        'password' => $password,
                        'deviceId' => 'onepiece',
                    ],
            ]);
            return json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
        } catch (ClientException $exception) {
            switch ($$exception->getResponse()->getStatusCode()) {
                case 402: // This only applies to co members
                    throw new SubscriptionRequiredException();
                case 403:
                    throw new BlockedAccountException();
                case 409:
                    throw new DuplicateEmailException();
                case 410:
                    throw new PasswordDoesNotExistException();
            }
            throw $exception;
        }
    }
}
```

`pwd` result on `MyClassServiceConfig` class directory
`/var/www/cms/web/modules/custom/mypackage/src/Services/Config`

But it seems to fail on the line `$configs = new MyClassServiceConfig(null, "mobile", "v1");` with the previously mentioned error :

```
1) Drupal\Tests\mypackage\Unit\mypackageUserAuthTest::that_we_can_authenticate_a_user
Error: Class 'Drupal\mypackage\Services\Config\MyClassServiceConfig' not found
```

Btw, I'm using drupal-project structure (https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project)

Comment: Try this command `composer -o dump-autoload` if dumping the optimized autoloader solves your problem, and not optimizing it still shows it, you have a typo somewhere in your directories or file names which prevent PSR-4 or PSR-0 autoloading.

Comment: @KevinWenger I have no error when I'm calling the module using the routes. The error `class not found` only arises when I'm calling it from the unit test class. As if the class is not correctly auto-loaded but only when called by phpunit

Comment: Yes I know that's why I ask you to run the `composer -o dump-autoload`. Did you try to run this command & then rerun `phpunit` ? It's still not working ? It's seems to be a typo in your dirs or files - but I'm not sure - this command will assert it - or not :D

Comment: @KevinWenger Yeah I've been running ```$ composer dump-autoload && vendor/bin/phpunit -c web/core --debug --verbose web/modules/custom/mypackage/``` everytime.

Ok, so I've run the ```composer -o dump-autoload``` then went loading the module through its route and it worked. I went loading it throughout phpunit but got the original problem... It's been days, this thing is killing me man...

Comment: Couldn you go in the directory of `MyClassServiceConfig` and run `pwd` then past the result here - I just want to be sure it's not a typo in your dirs names. Could you also run `ls -la` in this same dir to be sure its note a filename typo. You can then add this results to the question itself.

Comment: I added the `pwd` result to the question and double checked the result of `ls -la` letter by letter  and it matches. I found a solution I will be posting as an answer, not sure it's the correct solution though

Comment: Mmhh... that's very strange, could you also add the `MyClassServiceConfig` content file in your comment at least the Class declaration with namespace ? Maybe the class name is wrong (case sensitive with file name still autologind stuff). If not I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

So I spent days checking the path but it seemed that the files were not loading so I ended up adding the custom module to `autload-dev` part  `composer.json`.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "scripts/composer/ScriptHandler.php"
    ],
    "files": ["load.environment.php"]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": { "Drupal\\mypackage\\": "web/modules/custom/mypackage" }
},
```

Now at least it seems to load the module as I'm getting an other error related to Drupal Container
`\Drupal::$container is not initialized yet. \Drupal::setContainer() must be called with a real container.`

Answer (score 0):

It is an old question, the same thing happened to me, as I managed to solve it in my case it was as follows:

In the comment of the class where the tests are carried out, something similar to this should go:

The `@coversDefaultClass` annotation must go with the namespace of the class to test.

```
/**
 * @coversDefaultClass \Drupal\my_module\MyModuleClassName
 * @group my_module
*/
class MyModuleCaseTest extends UnitTestCase {

}
```

Maybe it will serve someone else